# I'm trying to insert a JPanel into a JFrame but the JPanel dont show off

Tags: java, class

So i have 3 classes.The first one is for creating a frame :

```
public class DrawingFrame extends JFrame{
    public DrawingFrame(){

        JFrame abc = new JFrame("TEST");
        abc.setSize(600,500);
        abc.setLayout(null);
        abc.setVisible(true);
        abc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Toolbar top = new Toolbar();
        abc.add(top);

    }
}
```

The second one is for JPanel :

```
public class Toolbar extends JPanel{

    public Toolbar(){

        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.setLayout(null);
        top.setVisible(true);
        top.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
        top.setBackground(Color.RED);

        JButton buton = new JButton("Hello!");
        buton.setBounds(40, 40, 40, 40);

        top.add(buton);

    }
}
```

And this is the main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawingFrame a = new DrawingFrame();
    }
}
```

My code prints out the frame but not with the panel.How i can fix this ?

Comment: set bounds, and add it to the frame before setting the frame to visible

Comment: Start with [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html). Then you might need to check what mean `extends JFrame`... you are creating a new `JFrame` in a subclass of `JFrame`. That's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to create an instance `JPanel` in a subclass of `JPanel`, same for `JFrame`. The instance is already one.

Use `this` to access the instance itself :

```
public Toolbar(){
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
    this.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JButton buton = new JButton("Hello!");
    buton.setBounds(40, 40, 40, 40);

    this.add(buton);
}
```

Second, if you use a `null` layout, you need to set the `bounds` of each componennt, as mention in [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

> Creating a container without a layout manager involves the following steps.
>
> - Set the container's layout manager to null by calling setLayout(null).
> - Call the Component class's setbounds method for each of the container's children.
> - Call the Component class's repaint method.

So adding the bounds to the `JPanel` will be enough with : `top.setBounds(0,0,150,150);` for example

```
class DrawingFrame extends JFrame{
    public DrawingFrame(){
        super("TEST");
        this.setSize(600,500);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            
        Toolbar top = new Toolbar();
        top.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 150);
        this.add(top);
        
    }
}

class Toolbar extends JPanel{

    public Toolbar(){

        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
        this.setBackground(Color.RED);

        JButton buton = new JButton("Hello!");
        buton.setBounds(40, 40, 40, 40);

        this.add(buton);

    }
}
```

And this will look like what you asked (in term of dimension and absolute position)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move  `abc.setVisible(true);` to the end

Also, use `this` instead of create `new` panel in toolbar. Same is in the case of frame as well

So, the below code will work:

```
public static void main(String...s) {
    DrawingFrame a = new DrawingFrame();
}

class DrawingFrame extends JFrame{
public DrawingFrame(){
    super("TEST");
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    Toolbar top = new Toolbar();
    this.add(top);
    this.setSize(600,500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class Toolbar extends JPanel{

    public Toolbar(){

    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
    this.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JButton buton = new JButton("Hello!");
    buton.setBounds(40, 40, 40, 40);

    this.add(buton);
    this.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Same comment in the frame, no need to create a `JFrame` instance in a subclass of `JFrame`. Note that **you changed the layout used**, I doubt this was the question !

Comment: Agreed @AxelH. Updated the answer as well